# R create a variable from row values

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis

I'm working with data from an "income/expense per home" poll done by the mexican government in which every tenement can contain more than one home.

There is a unique 6 digit folium number per tenement and a two digit indentifier for a single home in the tenement (00 means its the main home, 01 means its the second one and on); so it looks like this:

```
Folium.ten   Folium.hom
091001       00
091001       01
091002       00
091003       00
091003       01
091003       02
```

*note that the number of homes can vary

What I wish to do is to create a new variable upon this two to be able to identify each home easier, my thought looks like this (I'm open for different solutions):

```
Folium.ten   Folium.hom   Folium.id
091001       00           09100100
091001       01           09100102
091002       00           09100200
091003       00           09100300
091003       01           09100301
091003       02           09100302
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `paste`. i.e. `df$Folium.id <- do.call(paste0, df)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
df$Folium.id <- do.call(paste0, df)
df
#  Folium.ten Folium.hom Folium.id
#1     091001         00  09100100
#2     091001         01  09100101
#3     091002         00  09100200
#4     091003         00  09100300
#5     091003         01  09100301
#6     091003         02  09100302
```

Comment: got: Error in View : 'names' attribute [3001] must be the same length as the vector [1]
Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @AlfredoLozano  My code was based on the example you showed.  I assumed that you have a two column dataset.

Comment: @AlfredoLozano  Do you get error by `paste0(df[,1], df[,2])` as in the other methods?

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked by first creating the variable as NA's like this
>df$Folium.id<-NA
and then proceding with your code

Comment: @AlfredoLozano  Thanks for the feedback.  But, I don't know why you need to create a NA column.  In my example, I assumed that both the columns are 'character' class.

Answer (score 1):

`df$Folium.id <- paste0(dat$Folium.ten,dat$Folium.hom)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`df$Folium.id <- paste0(df$Folium.ten, df$Folium.hom)`